# Changing the indexes of  two dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array with the following output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [customer_id] => 7
        [language_id] => 1
        [variableitem_id] => 13
        [name] => QUESTION_HEADLINE
        [value] => Bitte geben Sie Ihren Downloadkey ein:
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [customer_id] => 7
        [language_id] => 1
        [variableitem_id] => 15
        [name] => QUESTION_BUTTON
        [value] => Start!
    )
)
```

I want to convert the output of the array to something like this

```
Array
(
 [QUESTION_HEADLINE] => Array
 (
    [value] => Bitte geben Sie Ihren Downloadkey ein:
 )

 [QUESTION_BUTTON] => Array
 (
    [value] => Start!
 )
)
```

I am using this code why it is not giving me proper array with index as names

```
    $final = array();
            foreach($data['variables_data'] as $vals){
                $final[$vals['name']]['value'] = $vals['value'];
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($final[$vals['name']]['value']);
                echo '</pre>';
            }
```

Comment: its very simple, you need just one loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$final = array();    
foreach ($arr as $vals) {
   $final[$vals['name']] = array('value' => $vals['value']);
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
echo '</pre>';
```

This should do the job. Output =>

```
> Array (
>     [QUESTION_HEADLINE] => Array
>         (
>             [value] => Bitte geben Sie Ihren Downloadkey ein:
>         )
> 
>     [QUESTION_BUTTON] => Array
>         (
>             [value] => Start!
>         )
> 
> )
```

Comment: If i want to print any value for example for the title i have to use 
$final['PAGETITLE']['value'] but its not printing it ?

Comment: are you talking about the same array strucutre presented above ?? It dont seem to have title there.

Comment: Thanks Rohan Its done sometimes mind doest not work so fast and we need output soon thats why i asked for help

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($originalArray as $orgSubArray) {
    $newArray[$orgSubArray['name']]['value'] = $orgSubArray['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$final = array()    
Foreach ($arr as $vals) {
   $final[$vals['name']] = $vals['value'];
}
```

This is irrespective of CI. This is really so simple..what did you try before coming here?

Comment: The solution u provided is wat i exactly did but its giving me only the values not with the names

Comment: Just cause you know the answer, you dont have to be that rude tandu, specially when the solution ur giving is not even right